# How to stop page moving down when clicking on anchor tag

Tags: html, css

Does anyone know how to stop the page from scrolling down every time I click on one of the anchor tags?

I'm hoping for the body of the page to stay still and the content on the right to scroll into view depending on which I click. But every time i click on one of the links it continues to scroll down.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap');
@import url("https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.8.3/font/bootstrap-icons.css");

html{
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}


body{
    margin: 0;
}

header{
    background: #000;
    height: 5vh;
    
}


/*-----------------------------------------------------*/

/* hero img */

.pp-hero{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    height: 75vh;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.pp-hero img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    position: relative;
    object-position: top;
}


/*-----------------------------------------------------*/

/* Content */

.pp-content{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.pp-content-container{
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: minmax(2, 1fr);
    position: static;
    height: 100vh;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.pp-content-navbar{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 1.5em;
    width: 80%;
    background: #eceff1;
    padding: 3em;
    border-radius: 0.5em;
    height: fit-content;
    grid-column: 1;
}

.pp-content-navbar a{
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    color: #00acc1;
}

.pp-content-navbar a:hover{
    color: #346e7a;
}


.pp-content-blocks{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 3em;
    height: 594px;
    padding: 0 2em 0 0;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
    grid-column: 2;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

.pp-content-blocks::-webkit-scrollbar{
    display: block;
    width: 3px;
    height: 1em;
}

.pp-content-blocks::-webkit-scrollbar-track{
    background: transparent;
}

.pp-content-blocks::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb{
    background: #B0BEC5;
    border-radius: 5px;
}


.block h1{
    font-size: 32px;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

.block p{
    line-height: 1.6;
    color: #B0BEC5;
    margin: 1.2em 0 0 0;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

.block *{
    margin: 0;
    scroll-margin-top: 2em;
}

/*-----------------------------------------------------*/

/* Footer */

footer{
    background: #000;
    height: 60vh;
}


.b-left a{
    color: #00acc1;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.b-right{
    color: #eceff1;
    font-size: 11px;
}

.b-right a{
    color: #00acc1;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    margin: 0 .5em;
}

.footer-socials{
    display: flex;
    padding: 0 0 3em 0;
    gap: .7em;
    justify-content: end;
    width: 75%;
}

.footer-socials a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    font-size: 13px;
    transition: color 0.3 ease-in-out;
}

.footer-socials a:hover{
    color: #00acc1;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    <header>
        
    </header>
    
    <div class="pp-hero">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1515094193635-40722cc342b3?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1770&q=80" alt="">
        
    </div>

    <main class="pp-content">
        <div class="pp-content-container">
            <div class="pp-content-navbar">
                <a href="#local-area-orientation">Local Area Orientation</a>
                <a href="#activities">Activities</a>
                <a href="#fine-dining">Fine Dining</a>
                <a href="#car-hire">Car Hire</a>
                <a href="#meet-&-greet">Meet and Greet</a>
                <a href="#airport-transfers">Airport Transfers</a>
                <a href="#photoshoot">Photo Shoot</a>
                <a href="#perosnal-training">Personal Training</a>
                <a href="#tours-and-area-experiences">Tours and Area Experiences</a>
                <a href="#spa-&-beauty-experiences">Spa and Beauty Experiences</a>
                <a href="#event-management-assistance">Event Management Assistance</a>
                <a href="#corporate-&-executive-relocation-contacts">Corporate and Executive Relocation Contacts</a>
            </div>
            <div class="pp-content-blocks">

                <div class="block" id="local-area-orientation">
                    <h1>Local Area Orientation</h1>
                    <p>Irrespective if your new to the area or if you are coming back for a visit; live like you’re a local. In a couple short hours, you can get “in the know”. Learn about who makes the best coffee, the newest restaurants, where to find epic bushwalks, spectacular snorkelling spots as well as all the other little local secrets that will maximise your stay. Avoid wasting time “figuring it out” by investing sometime with one of our local experts. You will gain the knowledge that normally takes months to discover yourself.</p>
                </div>

                <div class="block" id="activities">
                    <h1>Activities</h1>
                    <p>It’s always a long flight to Australia, so most people really want to end up having an experience of a lifetime. No matter what time of year, there is always something “happening” in Sydney but the trick is to know about it. Get your adrenalin fix, music, entertainment, food, cultural festivals or whatever else you are interested in. Please do contact our concierge team to help you set it up.</p>
                </div>

                <div class="block" id="fine-dining">
                    <h1>Fine Dining</h1>
                    <p>Our team has the pulse of Sydney and knows the latest and most reputable restaurants. Irrespective if you want a special intimate fine dining experience on the harbour or somewhere super-cool to hang out with some friends, let our team sort it out for you.</p>
                </div>

                <div class="block" id="car-hire">
                    <h1>Car Hire</h1>
                    <p>If you decide to rent a vehicle during your visit, your Personal Concierge can tell you whether it is advisable in your destination. Sometimes you can have a better time riding the ferry or taking a taxi. If a car is right for you, we will recommend one of our preferred suppliers and make the booking for you. Our established contacts know our homes and may deliver your car straight to your property, so you can settle in without the hassle.</p>
                </div>

                <div class="block" id="meet-&-greet">
                    <h1>Meet and Greet</h1>
                    <p>Let our team arrange a seamless arrival for you or your loved ones by coordinating, in advance, your entire party’s flight details with our on-site greeters. The arrival process at every destination is different but always stress-free with the procedures provided to you before you leave. All guests are shown the home’s ins and outs, given important contact numbers and local information by our local partners.</p>
                </div>

                <div class="block" id="airport-transfers">
                    <h1>Airport Transfers</h1>
                    <p>After a long flight, the last thing that anyone wants to do is flag a typical hot and stinky cab. Our team will be more than happy to organise one of our executive airport limousines so that the last part of your very long journey is as comfortable and effortless as possible.</p>
                </div>

                <div class="block" id="photoshoot">
                    <h1>Photo Shoot</h1>
                    <p>Our team of photographers starts by building a creative environment that results in stunning portraits the family will cherish for decades. Your experience with our team will be fun, relaxed, personal and unique. Your portraits will be beautiful, timeless and best of all, guaranteed to totally please.</p>
                </div>

                <div class="block" id="personal-training">
                    <h1>Personal Training</h1>
                    <p>Since you will almost certainly be enjoying the beach during your visit, allow us to help you feel great by setting up sometime with one of our personal trainers. Regardless of your age or physical fitness, we can help you in a way that works best for you; be it at the gym, outdoor boot camps, yoga or cross training. You can go alone or join a range of group work outs. It’s a great way to meet new friends and enjoy the community.</p>
                </div>

                <div class="block" id="tours-and-area-experiences">
                    <h1>Tours and Area Experiences</h1>
                    <p>There are plenty of tour outfits that explore the inner city as well as the outskirts of Sydney, however, over the years, we’ve identified the best operators. Time is precious, especially your free time, so please do allow us to help augment your journey to Australia by scheduling a memorable experience with one of our premium partners. Whatever your interest, we can help.</p>
                </div>

                <div class="block" id="spa-&-beauty-experiences">
                    <h1>Spa and Beauty Experiences</h1>
                    <p>Go on… you deserve it. We know all the best places for you to be pampered and beautified. If you want, we can even organise private massage and spa services to be sent right to the property you are staying in. Our Personal Concierge will coordinate with our local contacts to offer custom, relaxing treatments according to your exact needs. Private yoga instruction is another guest favourite. Whatever it is, don’t be afraid to ask.</p>
                </div>

                <div class="block" id="event-management-assistance">
                    <h1>Event Management Assistance</h1>
                    <p>We love to help people get together and celebrate. Over the years, we have found that for many of our guest’s purpose for coming to Australia is to either attend or host a wedding, anniversary, birthday or a range of other occasions. We have experienced event planners on our team to certainly help take the stress out of hosting a fabulous event whether it be for work or play!</p>
                </div>

                <div class="block" id="corporate-&-executive-relocation-contacts">
                    <h1>Corporate and Executive Relocation Contacts</h1>
                    <p>Let’s face it, moving across the city is stressful enough let alone moving to the other side of the globe. We have long-term relationships with a number of very talented (and well connected) corporate relocation agents whose job it is to be dedicated to making your move as painless as possible. Most companies today aspire to be an “Employer of Choice” and chances are, they have a policy and budget in place to make your move easy so that you can focus on what they want; being as productive as you can as quickly as possible. By taking a moment to reach out to us, we are very confident that you and your employer will quickly see the value we can provide at a relatively minimal cost.</p>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
    
    <footer></footer>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's the normal behavior

Answer (score 0):

For browsers that support css's `pointer-events` you can use:

```
.pp-content-navbar > a {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```